# Worker dying after receiving 1000s of tasks at a time in Django Celery

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am running a script that generates nearly 10000 objects. On save of each object, a Celery task will be called, so in just 1-3 min, Celery is receiving 1000s of tasks and its worker is dying (with state still showing as RUNNING).

So I need to restart again and again. Because I am restarting many times, many Python processes (that run Celery) are consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? please clearify

Comment: I have to do certain things so that worker shouldnt die, I shouldnt restart, it should respawn automatically, process should not accumulate like that.

Comment: I mention what i want in the prev comment

Comment: Can you provide some (pseudo)code from the task you run on the worker? Also have you tried to spawn more workers (celery has an option to dynamically grow/shrink the number of processes based on load)?

Comment: You should provide more insight what's happening inside the worker... Try to add a lot of logging to your celery workers, so you can observe where/how they get stuck...

Comment: I didnt try that spawning command

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly, you are having the same problem I had a few weeks back. Every so often, it seemed as if our celery worker was just freezing (we found it was actually receiving tasks but not executing any) and after restarting the worker it would rush through the tasks until it decided to freeze again.

The problem was solved by doing the following pip installs.

```
pip install https://github.com/celery/billiard/zipball/2.7
pip install https://github.com/celery/celery/zipball/asynwrite
```

I found the solution on the GitHub issue tracker page for the celery project but I can't find the exact ticket. [Heres a link to a similar issue though (that uses this as a solution).](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1310)

Comment: How were you running your celery workers? Was it through Supervisor or some other way?

Comment: It was a while a go but yeah, I believe it was through supervisor